# Routing question with MVC 3 and razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want my route to look like this:

/Products/Image11_full.jpg

My Razor looks like this:

```
<a rel="pgroup" title="@image.Name" href="@Url.RouteUrl("Image", new { controller = "Products", action = "Image", imageId = image.ImageId, size = "full" })" >
```

My route looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Image",
            "Products/Image{imageId}_{size}.jpg", // URL pattern, e.g. ~/Products/Image/
            new { controller = "Products", action = "Image" }, // Defaults will also match "GetSmallImage"
            new { imageId = @"\d+", size = @"\(full\|small\|medium\)" }
            );
```

I ether don't get anything (when I use a route name) or I get a route that look like this
/Products/Image?imageId=11&size=full which means it didn't find my route.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks
Irv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your size constraint is not correct. Define it like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Image",
            "Products/Image{imageId}_{size}.jpg", // URL pattern, e.g. ~/Products/Image/
            new { controller = "Products", action = "Image" }, // Defaults will also match "GetSmallImage"
            new { imageId = @"\d+", size = @"full|small|medium" }
            );
```

Comment: Yes this definitly works.  I had actually gotten it to work by completely removing the size constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `controller` and `action` from the `RouteUrl` call.  (Since they aren't in the URL parameters)